# Searching location in a sentence

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, gis, location

I'm working on a location extraction algorithm but haven't achieved anything considerable yet. For example in this sentence

> Riders on the B and Q lines will get some relief from construction as stations reopen, and a major project will soon begin at the Dyckman Street station.

"Dyckman Street" is location information. How we extract this information from a given sentence. (I tried to extract the words from a sentence starting with a Capital letter and search it against a db having city names, but it doesn't work always).

From where i can find an algorithm to extract this information?
Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember having seen [this library](http://cageclass.sourceforge.net/) when I was playing with [Named Entity Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition).

This [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=geographical+named+entity+recognition) might be a useful source of information as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are also a number of web services designed to parse geo-locations from text. For example Yahoo's PlaceMaker service at http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placemaker/

Comment: Thanks.. Yahoo placemaker is awesome and solved 90% of my problem. But I'll try to make this work around "Named Entity Recognition", so that i dont have to be dependent on any third party solution.